# How do I use a helper in my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im on Rails 4, I'm making a wine review app and I have a page for each individual wine. On the wine page (show.html.erb), I have a list of all the reviews given to that wine. I am trying to  make a simple method that displays the rating given in the review and I am trying to do it in my Review helper file

```
module ReviewsHelper
  def display_rating
    if self.rating == 1
        "<div class='btn btn-success'>:)</div>"
    elsif self.rating == 2
        "<div class='btn btn-warning'>:|</div>"
    else 
        "<div class='btn btn-danger'>:(</div>"
    end
  end   
end
```

For some reason Im getting an exception `undefined method 'display_rating' for #<Review:0x007fc89bae6148>` When I try and load my wine page. Ive tried moving the method to the WineHelper.rb file, but I get the same thing. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest passing the review as an argument to the helper, defining it as `def display_rating(review)` and calling it in the view as `<%= display_rating(@review) %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using view helpers to render  `display_rating`. Use of `self` is not accurate here.  You have to implement that helper method like:

```
def display_rating(obj)
  if obj.rating == 1
    "<div class='btn btn-success'>:)</div>"
  elsif obj.rating == 2
    "<div class='btn btn-warning'>:|</div>"
  else 
    "<div class='btn btn-danger'>:(</div>"
  end
end
```

Then call that method:

```
display_rating(@obj)
```

Comment: Ahhh.. That was it. I knew it was something simple. Thanks.

Comment: Also, it's a better practice to not hardcode html as strings, but use Rails' content_tag helper, e.g.  `content_tag(:div, ":)", class: "btn btn-success")`